# Convert the VS solution to using the new version of SAP Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Hi I have VS2022 and install the new latest SAP Crystal Report. When I opened the project with old version of Crystal Report. There is a popup. I selected "open the solution without conversion and saved the change.  Now this popup doesn't appear when I open the project. However I want to convert the solution using the new version of SAP.  What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but when I clean my local clone of the repo, this prompt comes back. There must be some file not under version control, maybe a *.user file, that affects this behavior.